# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException when retrieving a RSS feed asynchronously

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build a windows 8 metro app. A small RSS reader which retrieves feeds.

Therefor I try to get a feed async.

```
Windows.Web.AtomPub.AtomPubClient client = new Windows.Web.AtomPub.AtomPubClient();
client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("http://MyURI/index.rss")).Completed += completed;
```

Here is the callback function:

```
private void completed(IAsyncOperationWithProgress<Windows.Web.Syndication.SyndicationFeed, Windows.Web.Syndication.RetrievalProgress> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus);
```

Ok. Now my problem.

As long as I try to access object within my callback function, everything is working fine. But if I try to access objects of my class (in which the callback function is located) I got a COMException.
I try something like this: this.MyCollection.Add(...). I'm building a feedItem which I add to a collection within my class.

```
An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Eine Schnittstelle, die für einen anderen Thread marshalled war, wurde von der Anwendung aufgerufen. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

The strange thing is, that this access is working every second run of my app.

I don't understand whats going wrong here.

Does someone got a hint for me please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok. Solution: BlockingCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The solution is a BlockingCollection. It is threadsafe.